# Tips on applying for Standard Visitor visa when full time student

Tags: visas, usa, uk, customs-and-immigration

I need tips on applying for Standard Visitor visa while being and have been a full time student. I just recently completed my 2 year degree. I have been going full time therefore have not worked as much as I should have. I rely on funds from Uber and or money from my parents, I know it’s not ideal since they want to see I am employed. I am wondering what else I should include on my application to higher my chances of getting approved.

Details:

I was denied entry in 2018 (non genuine visitor) trying time stay with my boyfriend for 6 months. Lesson learned.

I am now applying (2020) for a standard visitor visa for 2 weeks to visit him and his family.

Comment: Are you a US citizen?

Answer (score 1):

The UK cares about applicants showing that:

- they are a genuine visitor
- they can afford the trip and can support themselves during the visit (or have a credible sponsor who will cover the costs)
- they have sufficient ties to their home country to convince the ECO that they will leave at the end of the visit.

You have a reasonable premise for the visit, but based on the information in your question you may well struggle to prove the other two points, particularly the returnability criteria. Reading this comprehensive answer may help your preparation [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

There really isn’t a magic bullet or any secret tips - you just need to look at the eligibility requirements and provide proof showing that you meet each one. This https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf may also help your understanding.